# Access Azure Key Vault secret in Azure Function

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-keyvault

I'm building Azure Function in python triggered with Event Grid events, which should be able to gather secret from Kay Vault.

I added system-assigned managed identity to my Function App, and then I was able to pick my App in Key Vault access policies. I gave it permissions like below:

[image: Permissions for function app]

*(I was trying different combinations at this one)*

Also I provided new app setting with reference to mentioned key vault.

[image: reference for key vault]

Unfortunetly when i try to check this value from code I'm unable to get this.

```py
logging.info(os.environ)
```

When I add another app setting, just with plaintext it works great.
I will be grateful for any ideas what else can be done.

Comment: Which combinations you used? Please try Get and List secret permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't figure out what you want to get with `os.environ`. I test with function It could work for me.

In function to retrieve key-valut if you already set it in appsettings, you could use `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("secrest name", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process)` to implement it.

[image]

[image]

Comment: os.environ is python method for listing all env variables.

Comment: So you could use `os.environ["setting-name"]` to retrieve it.

Comment: I did that with os.getenv('setting-name') and it returned None

Comment: What about `os.environ["setting-name"]`?

Comment: I test with `os.environ["setting-name"]`, it works. [Test pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yhVIS.png)

Comment: That's strange because i received another error:
`raise KeyError(key) from None
` . I think I willl try to redeploy all objects once again.

Comment: Make sure your appsettings has the `secretvalue`?

Comment: @Rob Ert, any process now? Could you access it now, if this could help you, please accept it as the answer.

Comment: I'm still unable to get those value from app settings. Can I ask how did you assigned Managed Identity for azure function? Also i looking for any tips about key vault permmisions. Right know I'm stuck in this one and have no idea what else can be done;/

Answer (score 2):

After hours of tests I found proper way to resolve this one.

In case of problems with Key Vault Reference make sure that App Function used for Azure Function is based on proper Hosting Plan.

[image]

Functions on 'Consumption Plan' are unaable to use Key Vault Reference. Same code on 'App Service Plan' works correctly.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following helper to get the values

```
namespace AccessKeyVault
{
    public static class GetKeyVaultValues
    {
        [FunctionName("GetKeyVaultValues")]
        public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)]HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
        {
            log.Info("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            string linkKeyVaultUrl = $"https://keyVaultname.vault.azure.net/secrets/";
            string keyvaultKey = $"KeyVaultKey";
            var secretURL = linkKeyVaultUrl + keyvaultKey;

            //Get token from managed service principal
            var azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
            var kvClient = new KeyVaultClient(new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(azureServiceTokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback));
            try
            {
                var clientIdRecord = await kvClient.GetSecretAsync(secretURL).ConfigureAwait(false);

                string KeyvaultValue = clientIdRecord.Value;

                return req.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Key vault secret value is  :  " + KeyvaultValue);
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {

               return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Key vault value request is not successfull");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'am using python and i want to build this function in python.