# Database connection string with Azure Keyvault in Azure Function local.setting.json in .NET Core

Tags: azure-functions, azure-keyvault

I am supporting an Azure Function someone wrote in C# in .NET Core 2.2.4. The function app is connecting to a database using a SQL Server account, and username and password are hardcoded in the connection string at the moment. We want to use Azure Keyvault now so that we don't have the password in the connection string.

Here is the connection with hardcode username and password in `local.setting.json file`:

```
"SQLConnectionString":"Server=tcp:xxxx-sql.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=abc-db;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=xxxx;Password=xxxxxx;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;"
```

Answer (score 0):

If your Username and Password are in KeyVault Secrets then You should give access to use the secrets as below [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75254252/17623802):

[image]

[image]

[image]

In configuration section Of function app Click on Add Application Setting and  Then type  password  and then below code

```
@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=https://mykeyvaultname.vault.azure.net/secrets/mysecretname/)
```

[image]

Then codes for using inside Azure Function are
[reference1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73961444) and [reference2](https://www.forestbrook.net/docs/azure/functionwithkeyvaultanddi.html).

Comment: I installed microsoft.Data.sqlClient libraries and updated the connection string to use    Authentication=Active Directory Integrated" . I am getting error message System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'authentication'.

Comment: I installed microsoft.Data.sqlClient libraries and updated the connection string to use    Authentication=Active Directory Integrated" . I am getting error message System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'authentication'. In order to use username and password from key vault, do I need to make other changes as you had pointed in references? Can we not just change the connection string to connect to database?  Username and password secrets do have necessary access policy setup in keyvault as you had mentioned.

Comment: Try using this ```Server=tcp:<sql-server-name>.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=<sql-database-name>;Authentication=Active Directory Integrated;Key Vault Secret=<key-vault-uri>;Secret Name=<name of  secret>
```