# How to create a function app that can write to data lake gen 2 securely?

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

I am quite new to these technologies but I would like some input because it is hard to understand what is happening for myself.

So what I did so far is to call an API, which in return sends me back a CSV file which I can then save locally. This is my logic for that.

```
URL = "https://www.example.com/id="

x = 108

bodyFile = URL + str(x)


data = pd.read_csv(bodyFile)

fileLocation = "C:/Users/..." + str(x) + ".csv"
data.to_csv(fileLocation, sep=',')
```

This works and no problem with this code however I want to run this on as a function app in azure where it does this monthly. It does give me a template however I struggle to see how to access the azure platform and upload this on the data lake gen 2 without explicitly putting in keys in my code which I definitely don't want to do for security reasons. I don't have access to change contributor or owner roles on azure.

Any help or any bits of code I can view with this example would be extremely helpful, thanks!

Comment: You have to have the keys in the code somehow, either as constants, or reading from an environment variable, or in a separate file.  BTW, it's not a good idea to hard-code paths like that.

Comment: how would I relay that as a function app? I just assume that you are deploying a function app and Also how would I change the file path (this is a basic version and will retool it for the function app but still would like to know how to do it properly)

Comment: On Windows, you can use environment variables like `APPDATA` or `HOMEPATH` to get the current user's home directory, with `os.environ[...]`.  When you deploy this, you will have to store the data in a database or to Azure blob storage, since there is no local drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to run this on as a function app in azure where it does this monthly

Yes, you can create a function app and then you can create a timer trigger trigger function to run once monthly.

> without explicitly putting in keys in my code

Yes, you need to put keys in Function apps code, you can use configuration section of function app as below:

[image]

You need to add which you added here in `function.json`
and you can use them.

> security reasons

You need to add them for sure inside the configuration or code, without them you cannot link functions and storage account.

For coding you use `Code+Test` inside your created function.

Comment: What about Key vault? doesn't that help or is that for a different purpose?

Comment: Inside KeyVault you can create a secret with the connection string but that still needs to be added in Configuration. [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75653796/database-connection-string-with-azure-keyvault-in-azure-function-local-setting-j/75658533#75658533)